# How to find all elements with a dynamic content-desc using Appium?

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, python-appium

My locator strategy is finding an element by its `content-desc` attribute. 
I have some text views on a screen that have this `contest-desc`: `report_description_textview_X_lines`, where `X` is a value between 0 to 3.

How can I get all the elements that have this dynamic content-desc?

I thought of 2 ways, but I do not know how to implement them:

1. Find all content-desc that contains the string `report_description_textview_`
2. Use RegEx in place of the changing value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

I defined my element locator as:
`self.the_elements = '//android.widget.TextView[contains(@content-desc, "report_title_textview_") and contains(@content-desc, "_lines")]'`

Then I got all the elements with that locator and as a list.
Below is how I checked for the dynamic value:

```
element = self.the_elements()[i].get_attribute('content-desc')
dynamic_number = int(title.split('_')[3])

assert dynamic_number in range(1, 3), f"Invalid number"
```

I split the content-desc of the element by the underscore character, then I took the third element after the split, which was the dynamic number of the locator.

Then I checked that the dynamic number must be in the range of 1 and 3. If not, it raises an assertion error message.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose something like that could work.

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@content-desc, 'report_description_textview_')]")
```

In general, when you want to get an element using a pattern, in most cases you probably need to use xpath.

In this case I get all the elements, with content-desc attribute that start with text `report_description_textview_`

I am not able to test if this code works so let me know!